# Is it possible to use ASSERT_NEAR in Predicate Formatter in googletest

Tags: c++, googletest

How can we use the ASSERT_NEAR or ASSERT_DOUBLE_EQ floating comparison without using the internal stuff of googletest inside an predicate formatter function?

```
template<typename A, typename B>
::testing::AssertionResult assertNearArrays(const char * a_expr,
                                              const char * b_expr,
                                              const A & a,
                                              const B & b,
                                              PREC absError = 1e-6){

      test each value of a with b
      using ASSERT_NEAR(a[i],b[i], 1e-6)
 }
```

That I think is not gonna work, I need to write my own comparison an returning an `AssertionResult` or `AssertionFailure`.
but it would be good to rely on the floating point comparison of googletest instead of my own...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write such test in only a few lines of C++ code:

```
template<typename T>    
bool is_near(T val1, T val2, T abs_error) {
  const T diff = std::abs(val1 - val2);
  return  diff <= abs_error:
}
```

Do you really need to follow exactly what gtest ASSERT_NEAR does? You probably want to provide additionl informations on the fail than what ASSERT_NEAR will do, something like:

```
  if (!is_near(a[i], b[i], absError))
    return AssertionFailure()
      << "The difference between a[i] and b[i]"
      << " is " << (a[i] - b[i]) << ", which exceeds absError, where\n"
      << "a[i] evaluates to " << a[i] << ",\n"
      << "b[i] evaluates to " << b[i]<< ", and\n"
      << "absError evaluates to " << absError << ", and\n"
      << "i evaluates to " << i << ".";
```

And *return AssertionSuccess()*; at the end of assertNearArrays

Comment: jeah I though one can properly use the internal stuff (which obviously in the internal namespace which suggests not to be used)
so the whole ULP comparision stuff can not get reused...

Comment: Just a tip for newcomers: Never implement a `is_near` function your self. Its more complicated than you think! Use boost floating compare facility or from other libraries
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/float_comparison.html#:~:text=Boost%20provides%20a%20number%20of,fabs(a%2Db)%20.